# Websocket scaling in google cloud or amazon cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, websocket, autoscaling

I've implemented WebSocket with java8 in tomcat server and hosted to google compute engine. I'm unable to do horizontal scaling with this environment, any idea how?

Also, I tried with AWS elastic beanstalk, deployed the app in nginx proxy and changed load balancer protocol to TCP. it seems working, the problem is a connection is closed after the 60s even after changing the load balancer's idle timeout as well as the connect draining time.

please suggest me solutions for any of the above.